# Limits of unital rings

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

Often times, a ring $R$ projects onto unital rings $eR$, where $e$ is an idempotent. Let $E$ be the collection of idempotents in $R$. $E$ can be made into a cofiltered partial order. Take $F:E\to\text{Rings}$ from $E$ to the category of nonunital commutative rings, where $F\left(e\right)=eR$. My questions are:

> When is $R\to\lim{F}$ an isomorphism?

> Can the ind completion of unital rings be embedded in the category of nonunital rings? That is, is the evident functor fully faithful?

Comment: Some nonunital rings may have no nonzero idempotents at all, e.g. $2\Bbb Z$.